# Reprojection of North Polar Stereographic binary to Lon/Lat grid (rasterio or gdal in python)

Tags: python, gis, gdal, rasterio

Now, I am working on  Stage IV dataset (Precipitation dataset in CONUS).
https://data.eol.ucar.edu/dataset/21.093

This is a binary data that shapes (1121 x 881) array and local 4km polar-stereographic grid.
The header files includes;
"polar stereo: Lat1 23.117000 Long1 -119.023000 Orient -105.000000".

I would like to convert this data to Lon/Lat grid for spatially matching to other dataset.
So, I need to convert this binary to geoTif first. 
Normally, I use rasterio to convert binary(array) to tif as follows;

```
def convert_np2tif(data, out_file,
                   width_of_pixel, height_of_pixel, lon_upper_left, lat_upper_left,
                   crs):
    affine = Affine(width_of_pixel, 0, lon_upper_left, 0, -1*height_of_pixel, lat_upper_left)
    with rasterio.open(out_file, 'w',
                        driver='GTiff',
                        height=data.shape[0],
                        width=data.shape[1],
                        count=1,
                        dtype=data.dtype,
                        crs=crs,
                        transform=affine
                        ) as dst:
        dst.write(data.reshape(1,data.shape[0],data.shape[1]))
```

However, this way need to specify the upper left lon/lat. I am not sure this value in polar-stereographic grid.

Does anyone know good way to convert this binary file to GeoTif and convert to Lon/Lat grid.
The way with not just rasterio, but gdal is all welcome. Thank you in advance for your adivice.

Answer (score 0):

This question contains everything you need: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278627/using-gdal-warp-and-gdal-warpoptions-of-gdal-python-api/341693

Pass `dstSRS` in `WarpOptions`, you won't need anything else